# Efficient `rm` of hard links?

Tags: linux, rm, hardlink

Suppose these is a file `foo`. Then, suppose I create a hard link:

```
ln foo bar
```

I can delete `bar` by running `rm bar`. However, it looks like when there are **lots and lots** of hard links, using `rm` is as slow as when deleting the inodes themselves (i.e. the last remaining hard links). Is there an efficient method for deleting a lot of hard links that are not the last remaining links to the inodes?

Comment: It should not make any difference how many hard links there are, `rm` should just be removing the one directory entry and decrementing the inode reference count. However if all the links are in the same directory it may be that it takes a long time to update the directory because it is large.

Comment: What's the use of having lots and lots of links, soft or hard?